# How to remove datatable column in c#

Tags: c#

i have an datatable  with  12 columns.now i need  to remove all the columns except at the position  "0"

i can remove individually by specifying the columns name. but i dnt want to do that.as it is not best way to code.

is there any other i can  do that

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123/remove-columns-from-datatable-in-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123/remove-columns-from-datatable-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go backwards through the columns and remove each one. You have to go backwards to avoid an index out of range exception.

```ccharp
// index should include zero
for( int index=table.Columns.Count-1; index>=0; index-- )
{
   table.Columns.RemoveAt( index );
}
```

**VB.Net Lovers:**

```
'index should include zero
For index As Integer = table.Columns.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    table.Columns.RemoveAt(index)
Next
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while(myDataTable.Columns.Count > 1)
{
    myDataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(myDataTable.Columns.Count - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you can take down the columns from a Data table object. What my code does is it will loop through the Data table objects and then remove the columns one by one.

```
    String strcolname = "";
    int i=0;
    //Get Data for the reader object
    using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {  
    // Load the Data table object
    dataTable.Load(reader);

    //Loop thorough the DataTable object
    for (i=dataTable.Columns.Count-1;i>=0;i--)
    {

    /* 
    To be more precise , specify the column name you dont want to get    deleted, 
    (you can add multilple column names here)*/

    strcolname = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();

     if (strcolname != "ABCD")
     {
      dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
     }
    }    
   }
```

Comment: With the coded above you can take down the columns from a Datatable object. What my code does is it will loop through the Datatable objects and then remove the columns one by one.

Comment: hope it helps, if you have any further queries please feel free to reach me.