# How To select Specific Column From DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataTable with 4 columns , 
I want to select one column without foreach or any other expensive loop and my result must be a new data table with one column ,How can I do this;

```
DataTable leaveTypesPerPersonnel = LeaveGroup.GetLeaveTypesPerPersonnels(dtPersonnel.row);
```

leaveTypesPerPersonnel has this columns :

```
[ID,Guid,LeaveTypeID,Code]
```

I want Filter leaveTypesPerPersonnel  wihtout foreach and get new datatable with just Column `[ID]`

> NOTE: Output must be a Datatable With one column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove columns from DataTable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123/remove-columns-from-datatable-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 leaveTypesPerPersonnel.Columns.Remove("Guid");
 leaveTypesPerPersonnel.Columns.Remove("LeaveTypeID");
 leaveTypesPerPersonnel.Columns.Remove("Code");
```

or

```
 DataTable dt= new DataView(leaveTypesPerPersonnel).ToTable(false,"ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run a quick LINQ statement against the data table.

```
var results = (from item in leaveTypesPerPersonnel
               select item.ID);
```

This will give you an IEnumerable if I remember correctly. It's not a DataTable, but might provide a solution to your problem as well.

Comment: This is a loop.  While he said ForEach in the question, I believe he meant any loop.

Comment: I believe the intent of the poster is not to have to do a for each loop of his data set to build a new structure, not that methods that utilize a loop internally cannot be utilized.

Comment: That is an interesting belief, the poster says "foreach or any other expensive loop".  Sound like he or she does not want a loop.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a try on how to search and convert the result to DataTable

```
 var dataTable = leaveTypesPerPersonnel.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().Where(x=> x["ID"] == 21).CopyToDataTable().DefaultView.ToTable(false, "ID");
```

> Or

```
 var dataTable = leaveTypesPerPersonnel.Select("ID = 21").CopyToDataTable().DefaultView.ToTable(false, "ID");
```

> Or

```
   var dataTable = leaveTypesPerPersonnel.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().CopyToDataTable().DefaultView.ToTable(false, "ID");
```

Comment: This is a loop.  While he said ForEach in the question, I believe he meant any loop.

Comment: Also this is only returning one row.  The poster is clearly asking for a table not a row.

Comment: my friend CopyToDataTable return a DataTable and ToTable also return a DataTable. its upp to him to specify which rows to return. he can have all rows in the DataTable

Comment: hahaha no i just added a third Or where you can have all rows without filter. i did not change anything.