# Trying to remove specific column from DataTable based on a property type

Tags: c#, datatables, propertydescriptor

I am trying to remove a column of specific type in the same way I would add one, except using `.Columns.Remove()`

I am using linq to grab the prop type and then a `forEach()` to remove the columns. I get an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Data.DataColumn'   Fabitrack   C:\data\repositories\FABITrack\Fabitrack\Models\ReportBusinessLogic.cs  141 Active

Below is my code:

```
//*Removing DOB from XLS file columns*/
var dob = from PropertyDescriptor props in pvPersonProps
    where props.PropertyType.Name.Contains("dob")
    select props.PropertyType;
foreach(PropertyDescriptor prop in pvPersonProps) {
    table.Columns.Remove(dob);
}
```

In case anyone is curious how I am adding to the table, here is some code.

```
var pvPersonProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(PVPersonDTO)); //get prop info from PVPersonDTO object
        var pvValResProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(PVValidationDTO)); //get prop info from PVValidationDTO object

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        /*Adding colums for Person collection*/
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in pvPersonProps) //iterate prop info from PVPersonDTO object and create column structure
        {
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`dob` is a collection in your case.

So you can do something like :

```
foreach (var dobItem in dob)
{
     table.Columns.Remove(dobItem);
}
```

or

```
var dob = (from PropertyDescriptor props in pvPersonProps
              where props.PropertyType.Name.Contains("dob")
              select props.PropertyType).First();

foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in pvPersonProps)
{
    table.Columns.Remove(dob);
}
```

Comment: thank you, however I still get a conversion error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Data.DataColumn' Fabitrack C:\data\repositories\FABITrack\Fabitrack\Models\ReportBusinessLogic.cs 141 Active

Comment: try to call `table.Columns.Remove(dob.ToString())` then you call delete column by name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123/remove-columns-from-datatable-in-c-sharp

Comment: It complies now, but I get a run-time error telling me that dob contains no elements. Perhaps my linq is faulty.

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd probably none property with `dob`