# Remove column by name

Tags: c#, datatable

**I want to remove the columns that have not a certain name**. I have been searching but can't find something that can help me.

This is what I am trying:

```
DataColumnCollection columns = dtExcelInforme.Columns;
foreach (DataColumn col in columns)
            {
                if ((col.ColumnName != "Code") || (col.ColumnName != "Denomination"))
                {
                    dtExcelInforme.Columns.Remove(col);
                }
            }
```

But this doesn't work because I am modifying the collection of columns.

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: create new one with the desired columns?

Comment: Just call `dtExcelInforme.Columns.Remove` ...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ is what I have seen but doesn't help me and the code you put is what I am trying

Comment: @LuckWallace so you couldn't put the names in a list, loop through that list and remove them by name...? There's a solution there that *would [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58115639/1797425)*.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ there's something similar, but what I want to do is remove columns that No contains a name.

Comment: @LuckWallace so why not put all the one's that you don't want removed in the list and then go through that list, I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ is there a example of code to do this?

Comment: @LuckWallace do this `dtExcelInforme.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(col => col.ColumnName != "Code" && col.ColumnName != "Denomination")).ToList()
                .ForEach(col => dtExcelInforme.Columns.Remove(col.ColumnName));` it's a `linq` version and all you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Çöđěxěŕ but this doesn't work :(